# Does anyone say that the virtue of the person we wrongly attack etc. reflects badly on us?

Tags: virtue-ethics

Does anyone say that the virtue of the person we wrongly attack etc. reflects badly on us? Let me explain... ordinarily, by which I mean non-philosophers and the like, we might feel worse about ***wrongly*** defaming or destroying someone of high status. Is there something analogously at work in more sophisticated ethics such that when I accuse the arhat of lying (or even just condemn them for lying) or attack the noble philanthropist for infidelity they in fact lack, then I am making a worse mistake and due to some vice in my charcater? Good people do not always recognize good people, but it is arguably easier for them to than most.

Comment: The Buddha evidently felt that Angulimala killing his mother would constitute a crime at least a thousand fold greater than his prior 999 cold blooded murders and so stopped him at personal risk. No, this is not directly re. virtue, but it suggests the same actions could be differently culpable